# How to check if there is data transfer over an available network or not?

Tags: android

I am using the code below to check if there is a network available or not , but sometimes 
the network is available but there's no data transfer , this is making my internet 
connection fails and throw an exception .

this is the code :

```
    public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

so , who can help me finding a solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you interested in if there is data transfer at a particular moment, or if data transfer is possible on an available network?

Answer (score 1):

I am using following code to check the connectivity because I think just geting the network info does not guarantee internet connectivity. Hence I think it is better to make an actual HTTP request to a remote URL and see if it is successful.

```
    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context cxt) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) cxt
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting() && canHit()) {

            Log.i(App.TAG, "Network connection available.");
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public static boolean canHit() {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            urlConnection.connect();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Good idea , but canHit() always returns false , do you have any idea about this ?

Comment: This code is tried and tested on emulator and devices as well. It does work for me without any issue. Hence I would suggest you to make sure internet is on.

Comment: Your connection may be too slow resulting into timeout, hence giving false everytime. I suggest you to try it with 10 to 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The user may be on a BT openzone or similar connection where they have a connection but do not have internet access until they supply a password via a web browser. Data connection issues are always going to happen, you just have to handle them in each case.

Also checkout

```
isConnectedOrConnecting()
```

Which checks whether the user is still establishing a connection. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html